# Running script containing kubectl commands in helm installation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a shell script that has several kubectl commands, I need to execute it as a part of helm installation.

`#!/bin/bash
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=username=$USER_NAME --from-literal=password=$passwrd`

I have written a job which execute this script.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "sagdfghd"

spec:
  template:        
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sagdfghd
          image: {{ .Values.jobs.dockerRegistry }}
          command: ["sh", "-c", {{ .Files.Get "scripts/myscript.sh" | quote }} ]
```

But as the script is running inside container it is not able to find kubectl command.

Any idea how can I run this script??

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What image does `{{ .Values.jobs.dockerRegistry }}` resolve to and does it have the `kubectl` tool installed on it? It most likely does not have kubectl installed on it, so you will have to add the kubectl install instructions in your Dockerfile. Those instructions will depend on what your base Docker image is. See the following link:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl

Comment: no its not and I cannot install it too.I am looking if we can run this script in k8s env itself instead of running it inside container. Because I want to create secret in k8s env not inside some container..

Comment: Since the `Pod` created by the `Job` will have a `ServiceAccount` attached to it, the kubectl tool running in the container will make calls to the cluster in which it's running via the `ServiceAccount` token, and will in fact create the `Secret` in the cluster, not the container (assuming it has the correct RBAC permissions). Try it out. Making calls to the kube-apiserver (e.g. via kubectl) from containers is not uncommon. Side note: creating a `Secret` object in a container makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Sudhir how did you fix it? Did you install `kubectl` in your docker file or what. I have a similar scenario/challenge

Comment: @Shammir  Instead of using command line , I used rest apis of kubernates to create the resources.

Answer (score 1):

@ericstaples provided [link to installation documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl) and it help to resolve issue:

> What image does {{ .Values.jobs.dockerRegistry }} resolve to and does
>   it have the kubectl tool installed on it?

It most likely does not have kubectl installed on it, so you will have to add the kubectl install instructions in your Dockerfile. Those instructions will depend on what your base Docker image is.

Since the Pod created by the Job will have a ServiceAccount attached to it, the kubectl tool running in the container will make calls to the cluster in which it's running via the ServiceAccount token, and will in fact create the Secret in the cluster, not the container (assuming it has the correct RBAC permissions).

Try it out. Making calls to the kube-apiserver (e.g. via kubectl) from containers is not uncommon.

Side note: creating a Secret object in a container makes absolutely no sense.